# Should we change veg*n questions to vegan/vegetarian ? (for search engines)

Tags: discussion, site-promotion, search

I've recently answered [this question (Are most electronics veg*n?)](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/1007/are-most-electronics-vegn), and while making further researches I realized that I never ran into this post itself on search engines (except on DuckDuckGo which had an older reference to the post, while it still included "vegan" in it's title).

This means that if someone is searching for this topic on most search engines, they will not find the result on vegetarianism.SE, which is - in my opinion - a bit absurd (having less web-visibility for a more compact title).

So... shouldn't we avoid using '*veg*n*' in post titles and use instead '*vegan/vegetarian*' (and also renaming existing questions) ?

Comment: I have previously rejected your edit of the said post when reviewing suggested edits and only now have I found this meta post. I can see why you have suggested the edit and I am now in favor of it. Is there a way of changing my review/approving the edit now? Perhaps one of the mods could do this?

Answer (score 10):

#### Yes,  that would probably be reasonable.

I see no reason not to keep using veg*n as a shortened version for post bodies, but it should be edited out of titles.  Most people won't know what it means, since I'm fairly certain it's specific to this site.

If you see any posts using this in the title, feel free to edit them out and replace them with "vegan/vegetarian", or something else if something else makes more sense.

Comment: And for this specific case, should I just put 'vegan' back, or 'vegan/vegetarian'? I don't exactly see why 'vegan' wouldn't be sufficient, but since it seems you made the change, I'm wondering.

Comment: @N.Cornet fixed, thanks. Also, probably best not to accept my answer just yet.  Nobody else had said anything yet.

Comment: OK, so I'll wait a little longer (for other answers/comments/votes) before making any edit.

Comment: "Most people won't know what it means" I am one of them. Moreover Vegetarianism and Vegetarian are not long words to write.

Comment: it's not specific to this site at all. But otherwise I agree entirely